# Symmetric indefinite matrix of fixed rank — manifold structure?

Tags: matrices, smooth-manifolds

I have been studying symmetric indefinite matrices of fixed rank, which have been rather useful for a particular application. I wonder if there is a way to parameterise these by a smooth manifold, e.g., to do optimisation over them.

I have seen quite a few examples of similar structures, like the cone/manifold of positive semidefinite (PSD) matrices, the fixed rank manifold, the symmetric positive semidefinite fixed-ranked manifold, etc.

I am not so familiar with the literature; perhaps someone can share their knowledge on the possible geometry of symmetric indefinite matrices of fixed rank?

Comment: You might want to take a look at slides 13-19 of Parrilo's [The convex algebraic geometry of rank minimization](https://web.mit.edu/parrilo/www/pubs/talkfiles/ISMP2009.pdf) (2009) [PDF]

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I am aware of the fixed-rank geometry, but I was referring to the restriction to symmetric matrices of this manifold. Specifically, is there a nice characterisation of the restriction of fixed-rank matrices to only the symmetric ones?

Comment: Have you taken a look at [Optimization algorithms on matrix manifolds](https://press.princeton.edu/absil)?

Comment: Have you considered starting with symmetric rank-1 matrices?